# How to validate upload file field using ng-file-upload in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need one help.I need to upload the file and display the validation message using `ng-file-upload in Angular.js`.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-class="{'myError': billdata.regdoc.$touched && billdata.regdoc.$invalid }">
    <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="regdoc" id="regdoc"  ng-model="regfile" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}"  custom-on-change="uploadFile" required="required" ngf-select="onRegFileSelect($regfile);" >
</div>
```

Now,this filed is allowing the image only.But here i need this field should allow only `pdf,ppt and .docx` files.If any other file will upload the validation message should display.Please help me.

Comment: look up `ng-pattern` in the github repo

Comment: @feniixx : ok..i did this.

Comment: `ngf-pattern="'.pdf,.ppt,.docx'" ngf-accept="'.pdf,.ppt,.docx'"`

Comment: @danial : No,its like `ngf-pattern="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"` this.